# Save statistics of wrong questions answers to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a quiz game, and I want to make statistics of questions that has been answered wrong.

I have a database with 3 tables: **Questions** (all questions), **Answers** (the alternatives for each question), **Games** (stats about each game sessions).

Right now I'm thinking of two alternative ways to make a solution for this.

1. Save each question ID into an array, then save the array
   into one record in MySQL at the end of the game.
2. Insert a new record with question ID into the table for each wrong
   answer.

Which of these options would be the best approach to solve my problem? If I'm correctly, the last one will be easier when I'm gonna query the database to show questions that has been answered wrong. Any input or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I'll go with 2 but I won't create a new record for every wrong answer. Instead, I would just insert the questions answered wrongly into a single field separated by a comma. That way you save rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to save each answer given into a separate row, exactly for the reason you stated. Querying such a structure will be much easier than having multiple answers stored in a single row.

I would structure the tables as follows

```
Question
ID | Text | whatever else you may need

Answer
ID | QuestionID | Text | IsCorrect | whatever else you may need

Game
ID | User | StartTime | EndTime | whatever else you may need

Stats
ID | GameID | QuestionID | AnswerID | AnswerTime | whatever else you may need
```

This would need adjustments depending on the kind of analysis you're planning to do on it, but you get the idea.

Counting the number of times a wrong answers has been given would be as easy as

```
select  t1.ID, count(*)
from    Answer t1
join    Stats t2
on      t1.ID = t2.AnswerID
where   t1.IsCorrect = 'N'
group by t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood correctly your question.  What follow is a possible solution for table statistics for answers if you want detailed information for each question / answer :

```
CREATE TABLE GAME_STATS (ID INT NOT NULL, ID_QUEST INT, ID_ANSWER INT, NUM INT);
```

ID is a sequence (you could omit this and make PK ID_QUEST, ID_ANSWER)
ID_QUEST refers to ID of table Questions
ID_ANSWER refers to ID of table Answers.
NUM is the number of times that answer has been selected.

You could consider to prepopulate the table for all possibile questions / answers (NUM = 0). 
At the end of every answer, you should update the NUM (+1) for ID_QUEST, ID_ANSWERS.

If you want register statistics for each session / user, you should add appropriate columns (ex. id_session, and/or user_id).
In this case you can't prepopulate table.  And you can register only wrong answers.